# scala, Jackson and @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I'm serializing some scala objects to JSON and need to add their original type into the serialisation.

I have the following classes

```
class Contact(taxonz : Seq[String]) { val taxons = taxonz}
case class Phone(number:String,taxonz : Seq[String]) extends Contact(taxonz = taxonz)
case class Mail(value:String,taxonz : Seq[String]) extends Contact(taxonz = taxonz)
```

It seems there is a Jackson annotation (I'm using jerkson) : JsonTypeInfo

However, I tried adding

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="scalaclass")
```

on the three classes above, I'm not getting back my 'scalaclass' property.

```
val persons = Seq(
      Person("000","bob denard",
             Option(Seq(
            Phone("0132354548",Seq("home")),
            Mail("bob.denard@sqli.com",Seq("business"))
          ))
      ),
      Person("001","aziz bouakaz ben aissef",Option(Seq(Phone("03332354548",Seq("business")))))
    )
    import com.codahale.jerkson.Json
    val jsonResult = Json.generate(persons)
```

with jsonResult value :

```
[
    {"id":"000","fullname":"bob denard","contacts":
            [
                {"number":"0132354548","taxonz":["home"]},
                {"value":"bob.denard@sqli.com","taxonz":["business"]}
            ]
    },...
]
```

Any idea ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because type info is metadata that Jackson handles completely, so you do not have to define properties for the sole purpose of passing type information.

If you would like to be able to see the property value, Jackson 2.0 will have such a feature (adding `@JsonTypeInfo.visible` property), but 2.0 has not yet been released (2.0.0-RC1 is out, and contains this feature).